# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^nn^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have worked out the following for this problem :

Let $${u_n} = \frac{x^nn^n}{n!}$$

Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{u_{n}}{u_{n+1}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{x(1+1/n)^n} = \frac{1}{xe}$$

Now for x>$\frac{1}{e}$ by ratio test we can say that the series {$u_n$} diverges and for x<$\frac{1}{e}$ the the series {$u_n$}  converges. 
However for x = $\frac{1}{e}$, the ratio test fails. So I apply the logarithm test which says that if :  $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\log\frac{u_{n}}{u_{n+1}} = L $$

1. L > 1 $\implies \sum u_n$ converges
2. L < 1 $\implies \sum u_n$ diverges

So applying this test : $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\log\frac{u_{n}}{u_{n+1}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\log\frac{e}{(1+1/n)^n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n -n^2\log{(1+1/n)} = $$ $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n - \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n* \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log{(1+1/n)}}{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n - \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n $$

This turn out to be of the type $\infty - \infty$. How do I proceed after this for the case x = $\frac{1}{e}$ ?

Comment: Do you know Stirling's approximation?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I am not aware of it. I will try to look it up. Will it help to give a solution to this problem?

Comment: The Stirling approximation will tell you that the series diverges.

Comment: The ratio test is usually $u_{n+1}/u_n$ not $u_n/u_{n+1}$.

Comment: The third equality in the displayed equation at the end is not valid when the two limits are infinity. The limit of $n-n^2\log(1+1/n)$ falls, as you noted, in an indeterminate case of the limit. Common techniques to resolve indeterminate cases are L'Hospital, which to apply it here you would need to transform the subtraction into a sum, or Taylor series. You can use that $\log(1+x)=x-x^2/2+x^3/3+r(x)$, where $r(x)/x^3\to0$ as $x\to0$. This will allow you to compute the limit and finish your argument.

Comment: @user85667 Thanks since  Stirling's approximation is not part of our coursework I can proceed with your suggestion.

Comment: Above I meant to write "you would need to transform the subtraction into a **quotient**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), we know that
$$n!<\mathrm e\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/\mathrm e)^n$$
Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1/\mathrm e)^n n^n}{n!}>\frac{1}{\mathrm e}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1/\mathrm e)^nn^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/\mathrm e)^n}$$
Simplifiying,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1/\mathrm e)^nn^n}{n!}>\frac{1}{\mathrm e\sqrt{2\pi}}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}_{\text{divergent}}$$
So we conclude $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(1/\mathrm e)^nn^n}{n!}$ is divergent.